# Creating a standalone node package archive for a lambda from an npm workspace directory

Tags: npm, aws-lambda, monorepo

I have a monorepo using npm workspaces which, after installing, looks like this:

```
/
  package.json
  node_modules/
  packages/
    lambda/
      node_modules/
      package.json
      package-lock.json
      <source code>
    cdk-stacks/
      node_modules/
      package.json
      package-lock.json
      <source code>
```

I'm needing to create a `.zip` file which can be uploaded to AWS as a Lambda handler, created from the code in `./packages/lambda`. However, some of the dependencies are hoisted to the top-level `node_modules`.

Is there a way, short of copying files to a new directory outside of the monorepo, to do an install such that all `node_modules` are installed at the root of a specific package so that a `.zip` archive isn't missing any dependencies?